# How to subscribe sailsjs rabbitmq-adapter

Tags: rabbitmq, sails.js

I have followed the steps explained in https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-rabbitmq. **And When I persist the data in Message DataModel, it gets saved in MongoDB as well as in RabbitMQ** ( CloudAMQP.com ). But i am seeing this error message in the sails lift console.

```
  sails-rabbitmq: waiting for orm hook to load before binding persistence handlers...
```

Any tips for avoiding this warning message?

As well my subscription program in api/services is not getting invoked.. For testing purpose, invoked this service from a sails controller, yet,

```
  Message.getSubscribeSocket({ where: { stream: 'random' } })
 .then(function (socket) {
socket.on('data', function (data) {
  var message = JSON.parse(data);
  // see, I told you it was "low-level" 

  // ... 
});
});
```

Thanks in advance for your guidance